# how to connect CI session by login user with flash action script?

Tags: php, codeigniter, actionscript-3

i didnt have any idea to connect as2/as3 with mysql by session login user. i just want to read somedata and input score from swf file to database. i need help how to excute this logic.

i have 2 login user by session CI login,

1. 1 users (admin) upload swf file (this work and run swf to the browser)
2. users 2 (student) play swf file (working as well)
3. on the latest frame i wanted to show in textfield "student name and score" and after that when users click button it will send to database.

im newbie for this, i haved test today on 15.00 WIB, i hope someone can help me

Comment: when i use this code, <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("edb");

$qr = mysql_query("select * from data_siswa ");

echo "lb=";
while($dt = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
 echo $dt['nama'].",";
}
?> it will connect database from * (all) table data_siswa, i just need to show by login users data

Comment: The easiest thing would be to just send the _"name and score"_ from AS3 to PHP by [using URL variables in an AS3's URLRequest to some PHP file that updates your database](http://www.shodor.org/~kevink/phpTutorial/davida_PassVarByUrl.php).

Comment: VC.One: how to implematation this method $_GET from flas->php>database

Comment: I don't know about using `$_GET` with the database. My idea is to solve sending from an AS3 variable (_eg:_ score) into a PHP variable like `$score_user1 = $_GET["user1score"]` this way you now have AS3's user1 score existing inside PHP. From there, use normal PHP functions to create, update or read a database. For example you could add user1 score to the database.

Comment: You need to create a `testfile.php` with code like `<?php echo "Score sent from AS3 : " . $_GET['user1score']; ?>` and now to send the score info from AS3 you do a URLRequest to your  server that has the PHP script. The URL request is to a path like `var myPath = "https://example.com/testfile.php?user1score=" + String( your_AS3_Score_variable );` ... Have your  AS3 request open in a new tab (option `_blank`) to preview the PHP result. When you understand how it works, then expand it to involve your database (_eg:_ no preview, just update a database).

Comment: VC.One: thx for your help and fast reply. im newbie for this, i cant get what u say. but its ok, i will try to learn

Comment: OK. It'll be faster if you say which part you don't understand... PS: I don't use CodeIgniter so if your exam is about testing your knowledge of CI, then I cannot help you. I'm here for _"(send) input score from swf file into database"_ if possible to help.

Comment: VC.One: idk how to start., i have scored from swf flash with name  "skor", idk how to use var to send swf input to php. i try like this "input_btn.onRelease = function() {
    lv = new LoadVars();
    lv.score = score;
    lv.load("http://localhost/(my.php)", "POST");
    lv.onLoad = function(src:String) {
        if (src) {

            trace(src);
        } else {
        }
    };
};" this is right as to send inpu skor to php?

Comment: You need to provide authentication for a SWF user on the backend side, then backend will handle requests for score updating. This is completely separate from working with SWF, although the SWF might have to be updated to be able to authenticate self with locally stored data and accept some "cookies" to sign/verify transferred data.

Comment: @Vesper: can u help me?

Comment: @ownrisk I see you're using AS2 which is very old (2005). It would have been easier if you used the more improved AS3... Anyways see if this works (I cannot test AS2 code): `var scoreA = "789"; input_btn.onRelease = function() { getURL("http://localhost/my.php?score=" + scoreA, "_blank"); }`

Comment: @ownrisk PS: Make sure the PHP is setup like the tutorial in my first/top comment's link.